# Declaring a variable within Define in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, constants

Is there a way to use a variable within a define statement; at the moment `$wpdb->prefix` works correctly; however `$useasprefix=$post->post_author` does not; it returns empty unless using `print_r($useasprefix=$post->post_author);` in that case it returns 1; ideally the prefix of the table would be the same number as the post_author

```
wp_cache_flush(); 
global $wpdb;
global $post;
$useasprefix=$post->post_author;

// Paths
define('Gocal_Plugin_AbsPath', str_replace('\\', '/', ABSPATH).'wp-content/plugins/go-cal/');
define('Gocal', WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/go-cal/');  


// Tables  
define('GOCAL_Set_table',$useasprefix .'_gocal_settings');
define('GOCAL_Cal_table',$useasprefix .'_gocal_calendars');
define('GOCAL_Day_table',$useasprefix .'_gocal_dopbs_days');
define('GOCAL_Res_table',$useasprefix .'_gocal_reservations');
define('GOCAL_Forms_table',$useasprefix .'_gocal_gocal_forms');
define('GOCAL_Forms_Fields_table',$useasprefix .'_gocal_forms_fields');
define('GOCAL_Form_Options_table',$useasprefix.'_gocal_forms_select_options');
```

The post was supposed to be the global wordpress `$post` object; I have updated it now;

```
wp_cache_flush(); 
global $wpdb;
$post = get_queried_object();
$useasprefix=$post->post_author;

// Paths
define('Gocal_Plugin_AbsPath', str_replace('\\', '/', ABSPATH).'wp-content/plugins/go-cal/');
define('Gocal', WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/go-cal/');  


// Tables  
define('GOCAL_Set_table',$useasprefix .'_gocal_settings');
define('GOCAL_Cal_table',$useasprefix .'_gocal_calendars');
define('GOCAL_Day_table',$useasprefix .'_gocal_dopbs_days');
define('GOCAL_Res_table',$useasprefix .'_gocal_reservations');
define('GOCAL_Forms_table',$useasprefix .'_gocal_gocal_forms');
define('GOCAL_Forms_Fields_table',$useasprefix .'_gocal_forms_fields');
define('GOCAL_Form_Options_table',$useasprefix.'_gocal_forms_select_options');
```

Comment: where is `$post` defined?

Comment: It seems like something that should work, if `$post->post_author` has a concatenatable value at the time of defining

Comment: Seems like you're using $post before it's defined. When you say print_r(... returns 1. Are you using `echo print_r(`. If so that's why you're seeing 1. `$post->post_author` isn't an array so you shouldn't be using print_r on it. `$post->post_author` is an integer.

Comment: The post was supposed to be the global wordpress $post object; I have updated it now to query that object. If I var_dump ($useasprefix) it returns  - string(3) "628"
I can't see why that variable is then not output within the define statement?